# Tar command provides slightly different outputs when run from BASH script vs running manually

Tags: bash, shell-script, tar

I am trying to run the following script:

```sh
    #!/bin/sh
    pm2 stop process
    
    cd ~/userdata/
    
    tar -czvf backup.tar.gz Config
    
    mv backup.* ~/backups/
    
    pm2 start process
```

When the script is run the backup.tar.gz output file excludes any empty dirs but, when I run the tar command manually on the command line it includes them. I would like to have the script include all all files and sub-dirs whether or not they are empty.

Edit:

Using `tar --version` I get the following output: `tar (GNU tar) 1.34 Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>. This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.`  using `tar -tvf` on the archive made with the script the empty dir is not there and when I run that on the archive made with the manual command the dir is included.

Comment: Which version of `tar` (`GNU tar`?) are you using? Can you confirm that empty directories are not archived using `tar -tvf`?

Comment: Using `tar --version` I get the following output:
`tar (GNU tar) 1.34
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
`
using `tar -tvf` on the archive made with the script the empty dir is not there and when I run that on the archive made with the manual command the dir is included.

Comment: 1. Please update your question with the above information. 2. I ran `tar -czvf` from inside a script on a directory containing several empty files and empty directories. It archives all files in the directory. Does not including `pm2 stop/start process` line in your script has the same effect? Is `Config` related to `pm2` process?

Comment: 2. I tried running the script on a test directory with empties and was able to replicate your results. I tried on the actual target omitting the `pm2 start/stop process` and it is still not including the empty directory.  The `pm2` process does access the files for settings that have been stored on the user interface. (not sure if that's what you meant).

Comment: I have identical tar version and tried it. In my case, it works identically in script (/bin/sh) and manually in bash.

Comment: What's the result of *sourcing* the script?

Comment: What is the result of executing *all* the commands from the script entered manually on the command line?

Comment: everything in Config/ gets archived including the empty directories.

Comment: Maybe check `type tar` in both scenario. May also check with `tree` (by redirecting its stdout to some file, if Config contains a lot of stuff).

Comment: What happens when you replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash -i`?

Comment: As @TomYan noted, there is probably some alias for tar in your _$HOME/.bashrc_ or _$HOME/.bash_profile_. The only two differences between a shell running the script with `#!/bin/sh` shebang and Bash accepting commands typed at the prompt are 1) with `#!/bin/sh` shebang, whatever is at _/bin/sh_ is run, usually having POSIX mode turned on, 2) shells running scripts are by default non-interactive (unless explicitly instructed otherwise), those accepting typed commands at the prompt are interactive. Interactive shells source additional startup files.

Comment: Also, some terminal emulators start shells as login shells, sourcing additional different startup files. There might be aliases or environment variables defined in those files (Bash [sources _$HOME/.bash_login_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoked-as-an-interactive-login-shell_002c-or-with-_002d_002dlogin)).

Comment: `type tar` gives me: `tar is /usr/bin/tar` if i run the command manually and through the script.